# Combine set of images to create background image

Tags: javascript, html, css

If i had a folder `books_images` with set of images

```
- books_images 
-- 1.jpg
-- 2.jpg
-- 3.jpg
-- 4.jpg
-- 5.jpg
-- 6.jpg
```

How can i iterate through this folder and pick up (number) of images in random way each time and combine all into one single image to be used as background for `index.html`

just like this one and if you make refresh, it makes different sequences in images.

[image]

Comment: You can have multiple css background images, and you can position them individually. You would be able to set the background url programatically using javascritpt.

Comment: you have to come with the code you have tried till. On SO no one will give you readymade code. We can help.

Answer (score 1):

This little demo works, I have only done 4 images from a selection of 6. You can amend the calls to 'randomNo' as needed. You would need to expand the css rules to fit the number of images you want to display at once.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Background Demo</title>

</head>
<body onload="randomBackground()">

  <script>
    function randomNo(min, max) {
        min = Math.ceil(min);
        max = Math.floor(max);
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    }
    function randomBackground() {
        var element = document.createElement('style'), sheet;
        document.head.appendChild(element); //create a stylesheet
        sheet = element.sheet;

        var styles = 'body {';
        styles += 'background: url(images/'+randomNo(1,6)+'.jpg), url(images/'+randomNo(1,6)+'.jpg), url(images/'+randomNo(1,6)+'.jpg), url(images/'+randomNo(1,6)+'.jpg);'; //Build the random background
        styles += 'background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;'
        styles += 'background-size: 50vw 50vh, 50vw 50vh, 50vw 50vh, 50vw 50vh;'
        styles += 'background-position: 0 0, 50vw 0, 0 50vh, 50vw 50vh;'
        styles += '}';

        sheet.insertRule(styles, 0); //add rule to new sheet

    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you, i will try to edit the code such doing iteration through images folder since image names might be not known, only i know the extention *.jpg

Answer (score 0):

if you have for example 20 images in your folder , you should give a random number between 0 and 20 and set it as a variable at end of your folder directory , for example :

```
let myRandomNumber = Math.random() * 20;
let img = document.querySelector("img");
let randomPath = '/your-folder-name/' + myRandomNumber + '.jpg';
img.src = randomPath;
```

if you want to iteration through a folder and combine a random number of image :

```
let images = document.querySelectorAll("img");
let path = '/your-folder-path/'

const myArr = []
while(myArr.length <= images.length){
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    if (myArr.indexOf(randomNumber) === -1) {
        myArr.push(randomNumber);
    }
}

if(images){
    images.forEach((img , index) => {
        img.src = path + myArr[index]
    })
}
```

Comment: OP want an iteration through a folder and combine a random number of image not only one